# How to sort a SimpleFeatureCollection using GeoTools?

Tags: java, geotools

I have a featurecollection:

```
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(dbFeatureType);
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = FeatureCollections.newCollection();
while (mifReader.hasNext()){      
  in = (SimpleFeatureImpl) mifReader.next();
  SimpleFeature dbFeature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
  for(AttributeDescriptor ad : adList){
    String name = ad.getLocalName();
    Object attrValue;
    attrValue = in.getAttribute(name);
    if(attrValue instanceof String){
      String string3 = new String((attrValue.toString()).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "cp1251");
      if(name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(kadname.trim())){
        dbFeature.setAttribute("kadnum", string3);
      }
    }
    if (attrValue instanceof Geometry){
        idn++;
        com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry geom = (Geometry) in.getAttribute(name);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("id", idn);
        System.out.println("after insrt="+idn);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("deleted", deleted);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("the_geom", geom);
        dbFeature.setAttribute("status_id", status_id);

    }
    collection.add(dbFeature);
    }
}
```

Its all okay. But when I put this collection in Data Base i get a reversed items. So i want to sort or reverse items in this collection. But how to do this?
I try to use this:

```
        collection.sort( new SortBy() 
{ 
    @Override
            public PropertyName getPropertyName() { return YourPropertyNameImpl("id") ; } 
    @Override
            public SortOrder getSortOrder() { return SortOrder.ASCENDING; }
});
```

But I don't understand what is `YourPropertyNameImpl`.

**UPDATE**

Okey. I try to put features from my collection to another collection:

```
    Iterator iterator = null;
    int count;
    iterator = collection.iterator();
    while( iterator.hasNext()){
        SimpleFeature feature = (SimpleFeature) iterator.next();
        coll.add(feature);
        System.out.println("Coll= "+coll.features().next().getProperties("id"));
    }
```

But get same result(. In this case i need to read collection from last element to first. Its possible?

Comment: replace SortOrder.ASCENDING; with SortOrder.DESCENDING ?

Comment: What its mean? Sorry im new in GDAL.

Comment: I think that this is GeoTools not GDAL, but where you see the line with ASCENDING in it replace that word with DESCENDING and the collection will be sorted in the other order.

Comment: Okey. Can you tell me about `YourPropertyNameImpl("id")` what its mean? I try to use SimpleFeatureImpl but cant get a PropertyName.

Comment: can you add a link to where you found this code so I can see the context?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044215/how-to-resort-a-collection-in-java/13044303#comment17713426_13044303

Comment: have you read http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html

Comment: I read this now but can find something about collection sorting.

Comment: Query query = new Query( typeName, filter);
SortBy sort = filterFactory.sort( sortField, SortOrder.DESCENDING);
query.setSortBy( new SortBy[] { sort } );

SimpleFeatureCollection sorted = source.getFeatures(query);

Comment: What is `filer` and `source`?

Comment: Your database is not indexed ?
The INSERT order in a relational database should not be relevant ...

Comment: Yeah. Traing to insert features to data base in order which they writting in tab file is wrong way. My question was stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Just to help anyone else who ends up here as I did recently! There is a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5416) in GeoTools that prevents DESCENDING working as a sort order. See this [PR](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1188) for the fix which will be applied shortly.

**UPDATE**

This is now fixed in all GeoTools releases from 14.4 and 15.1